# Overriding __copy__ for Django models?

Tags: python, django

When copying a Django model object, I would always expect it to not have the same identity (aka primary key) as the source object I am copying from. Usually you do something like this:

```
copy = copy.copy(source)
copy.pk = None
copy.save()
```

But I would like to make this automatic like this:

```
class MyModel(Model):
    def __copy__(self):
        result = MyModel.__new__(MyModel)
        result.__dict__.update(self.__dict__)
        result.pk = None
        return result
```

So I now can just do:

```
copy.copy(my_Model).save()
```

Until now this seems to work. However, looking at what Django does with model objects in `__init__` and `__new__` for example, I keep wondering whether this is indeed allowed and conforms to the Django principles. Suprisingly Django models seem not to override `__copy__`.

Comment: Thanks matsjoyce, didn't know.

Answer (score 0):

As you can find in the [Django source (`Model.__hash__`)](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L504), Django just uses the `__hash__` method (which uses the `pk`) to determine the hash for the method. So it won't clash with that.

Further, the `__eq__` method also compares by `pk` so it doesn't matter for that either.

Long story short, there's nothing stopping you from overriding `__copy__` as long as you make sure the `pk` value is changed in the process.